# Is portlet an obsolete techology?

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, portlet

This is not meant to be an argumentative question.
I heard about portlets but trying to Google for tutorials etc I could not find any really good or updated tutorial.
Most seem rather outdated and not one I can say it is a good one.
Is my searching bad or is Portlet an outdated technology?

Comment: It is not an answer but here is one pretty up-to-date tutorial: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/training/kp/j-kp-portlet/index.html

Comment: @AlexR that link does not work.

Comment: Well, hopefully it worked almost 2 years ago when it was posted...